# How to set role-based login for jenkins in keycloak

Tags: jenkins, openid, keycloak

I am very beginner of keycloak. I need some help.

I have SSO solution and I want to integrate it with jenkins.
In this point, I want to permit some users based role.

OpenID -- keycloak -- jenkins : all users who are in openid can login jenkins (I don't want)

OpenID -- keycloak (check role) -- jenkins : all users who are in openid and also have specific role in keycloak can login jenkins (I want)

I think this is very simple and common example of using keycloak, but I can't find the solution.

steps I did are here.

1. install keycloak plugin in jenkins.
2. install keycloak (version 5.0.0 using helm)
3. create realm
4. create Identity Providers (OpenID)
5. create client (named jenkins)
6. Installation tab > copy Keycloak OIDC JSON to Jenkins

(refer. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/keycloak-plugin)

now, I can login jenkins successfully.

7. create role in Roles in realm
8. In (jenkins) client, turn on Authorization Enabled
9. Authorization tab > Policies tab > Create Policy > role

select realm role and check required

10. update JSON in Jenkins config.

It's done, but it does not works.

Comment: Did you manage to enable the roles? I can follow you until Point 7.
What do you mean with "8. turn on authorization enabled"? "9. Authorization tab" ... where? Keycloak or Jenkins? Can't find that tab anywhere ...

Answer (score 9):

I managed it the following way (Using Keycloak 8.0.1, Jenkins 2.208):

**Keycloak**:

1. create realm
   [image]
2. create client "jenkins" - set root url to Jenkins-url (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8080)
   [image]
3. In client "jenkins" select tab "installation" - format "keycloak OIDC JSON" - copy to clipboard for Jenkins Setup below
   [image]
4. create  role "jenkins_admin"
5. create role "jenkins_readonly"
   [image]
6. create user "admin" and assign role "jenkins_admin"
7. create named user and assign role "jenkins_readonly"
   [image]

**Jenkins**

1. verify that you have the necessary plugins installed (if not, install them):

- "[Keycloak Authentication Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/keycloak)"
- "[Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth)"
- "[Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/)"

2. Switch authorization mode to **Role-Based Strategy** by going in "Configure Global Security" - Select "Authorization": "Role-Based Strategy" and then click on save
   [image]
3. Add Keycloak authentication JSON by going to "Manage Jenkins" - "Configure System" - "Global Keycloak Settings" and paste the previously copied JSON  (Keycloak step 3) to "Keycloak JSON" Area
   [image]
4. Verify that an admin role is present by going to "Manage Jenkins" - "Manage and Assign Roles" - "Manage Roles" - "Global Roles". If not present, add the role "admin" with all checkboxes selected; then click on SAVE
5. Add a "read_only" role by going to "Manage Jenkins" - "Manage and Assign Roles" - "Manage Roles" - "Global Roles" and add role "read_only" with "Overall Read" selected; then click on SAVE
   [image]
6. Create group "jenkins_admin" and assign to "admin" role by going to "Manage Jenkins" - "Manage and Assign Roles" - "Assign Roles" and add group "jenkins_admin" to global roles; then select "admin" and click on SAVE
7. Create group "jenkins_readonly" and assign to "read_only" role by going to "Manage Jenkins" - "Manage and Assign Roles" - "Assign Roles" and add group "jenkins_readonly" to global roles; then select "read_only" and click on SAVE
   [image]
8. Change the "Security Realm" to **Keycloak Authentication Plugin** by going to "Configure Global Security" and selecting "Security Realm": "Keycloak Authentication Plugin", then click on save.
   [image]
9. Logout

Now, when you try to perform a login, you should be redirected to the Keycloak login page.
Try to log in as admin with admin rights, and as named user with read only rights.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you very much

Comment: perfect man! only one thing missing  which is : what's the configuration-as-code of the jenkins-side configuration.

Comment: I am struggeling at bullet #4 `Manage Jenkins - Manage and Assign Roles - Manage Roles - Global Roles - (if not present) add role "admin" with all checkboxes selected - SAVE`. I do not have the option `Manage and Assign Roles`, even though named plugins are installed.
How to select the option?

Comment: @Fabiansc - You need to have the [Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) installed and enabled to see the `Manage and Assign Roles` in `Manage Jenkins`  interface. You can enable it in `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure Global Security` - `Authorization`

Answer (score 2):

Besides [answer of Christop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59305990/747579)  :

- you need to configure a Mapper for Group Membership under the keycloak client.
- validate that by making sure that "groups" comes in the scope of access token.

---

Another point, you can use one of two plugins :

- Either keycloak plugin
- Or [oic-auth plugin (open id connect)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/oic-auth/) indeed, keycloak implements the openid connect protocol at the end.

---

Last point :

- make configuration-as-code an essential plugin in your jenkins stack.
- Check always examples in configuration-as-code plugin, it might help a lot. For this case, these links can help a lot :

  - https://github.com/jenkinsci/oic-auth-plugin/pull/78/files
  - https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/issues/994#issuecomment-523643362

Comment: what is the correct way to create the group mapping?  without this, I'm stuck in a loop