# Jenkins "Role-based Authorization Strategy" Plugin with OIDC - how to configure Project Roles?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, keycloak

Actually I'm using Jenkins 2.234 with "[Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/)" Plugin (2.16) and
Security Realm "Jenkins’ own user database".

This works perfect using "Project Roles" for fine grain Permissions.

Now I want to switch the Security Realm to "[Keycloak Authentication Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/keycloak/)" (2.3.0) and got it working using "Global Rules" (See [How to set role-based login for jenkins in keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042425/how-to-set-role-based-login-for-jenkins-in-keycloak/59305990#59305990)).

Nevertheless the same Setup does not work for the "Project Roles".

Any Ideas what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks,
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not a problem of the functionality but on the caching behaviour of Jenkins.

After I restarted Jenkins the "Project Roles" were active.
See
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61470 and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61508